# How to separate words by numbers from a string in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a text file called commands.txt which contains some commands followed by some arguments.
Example:

```
STOP 1 2 4
START 5 2 1 8
MOVE
CUT 0 9
```

I want to read every line from this text file and to print something like this

```
STOP: 1 2 3
START: 5 2 1 8
MOVE:
CUT: 0 9
```

I read every line with fgets and then I tried using sscanf but doesn't work.

```
char line[100]   // here I put the line
char command[20] // here I put the command
args[10]         // here I put the arguments



 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    FILE *f;
char line[100];
char command[20];
int args[10];

f=fopen("commands.txt" ,"rt");
while(!feof(f))
{
fgets(line , 40 , f);
//here i need help
}
fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: for the love of God, please avoid `sscanf()` and any variants thereof! The only thing they surely do is leading to even greater confusion.

Comment: Here's a hint - walk through `line`, one character at a time. If it's not a space, output it. If it is a space, output a `:`, then output the space. After that, just output all the rest of the characters without looking at them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about the whole thing in the wrong way.  If you wanted to collect the commands separate from the arguments to do something with them, then you need test using ctype.h.

However, for the way you want to do the output, you don't really need to save all those buffers.  Just print the whole thing, filling in your colon where you need it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int main(){

      FILE *f;
      char *buf;
      buf = NULL;
      int i = 0, size;

      f=fopen("commands.txt", "r");
      fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
      size = ftell(f);
      fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
      buf = malloc(size + 1);
      fread(buf, 1, size, f);
      fclose(f);

      for(i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        while(isalpha(buf[i])){
          printf("%c", buf[i++]);
        }
        printf(":");
        while(buf[i] == ' ' || isdigit(buf[i])){
          printf("%c", buf[i++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
    return 0;
    }
```